# Avoid using window.onload but still grab a script and then run a function

Tags: javascript, html, dom, get

I am running a function through a jupyter notebook. Due to some reasons the window.onload function does not seem to work.

For example (this is just an example, not the actual code I am working with - I know this is not best practice), lets say I have the following page:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js"/>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
// use some jquery function here
}
</script>
```

Is there a way to convert this into something like this using vanilla javascript:

```
<script>
get("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js").then(
// use some jquery function here
)
</script>
```

Comment: What happens when you used the window.onload handler? Is there any error or nothing happens?

Comment: @ThomasBui, so the window.onload function never fires - I think it may be something to do with Jupyter. I put an alert(10) inside the onload callback function but it never runs.


Basically I want a javascript function to fire using the jupyter API for a scala notebook; https://almond.sh/docs/api-jupyter.html#display-data

Comment: Maybe you need to listen for the jupyter specfic event `notebook_loaded.Notebook`?